# Should I use a unique prefix for all functions within a Python module?

Tags: python, function, namespaces

I have a file in my Python project containing a number of functions that will modify various data objects within my app.  I've called this file `conditions.py`.

Every function within this file, I've prefixed with `condition_` (e.g. `condition_limits()` will limit integers between a specified range, `condition_in_list()` tests for a given value in a given list...).

My question: Given that to use these functions in other files, I will be importing `conditions`.  **Do I need to prefix my functions in this file at all?**

Will `conditions.limits()` be sufficiently unique and equal to `conditions.condition_limits()` in use?

I ask because I am having a little trouble understanding python's personality with regard to structure, scope, namespace and unique names.  I would prefer to not prepend all of my functions for sake of readability and overall cleanliness.

Thanks!

Comment: No. Use modules, they are namespaces, and serve your purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No! Python has namespaces, so you do not have to use prefixes.
Prefixes are only useful for languages with out of namespaces like C or ObjC

Comment: So, if I have `function()` defined within `file.py`, anywhere that I import `file`, I can use `file.function()` without fear of a naming conflict?

Comment: Fantastic.  Thanks for the answer.